# how can i prevent a selected option from opening the url

Tags: jquery

I'm wanting to import each option value via ajax , but i haven't had any success stopping the option from redirecting to the original site when selected

existing html

```
<select name="LOCATION" size="1" onchange="self.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
<option>Jump To...</option>
<option value="https://www63.myfantasyleague.com/2021/options?L=43570&amp;O=123&amp;MONTH=1&amp;YEAR=2021">Feb 2021</option>
<option value="https://www63.myfantasyleague.com/2021/options?L=43570&amp;O=123&amp;MONTH=2&amp;YEAR=2021">Mar 2021</option>
</select>
```

trying to stop the option from triggering to the url , so i can get the url and bring into my page

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // not working to stop the selected option from opening new url
    var href = $('option:selected').val();
    console.log(href);  
});
```

Comment: Option values are what they are. If you want them to be different them make them different ... either when the options are made or when the values are read back from the DOM. In either case it's just a question of string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

That inline event isn't really attached on the DOM load, so you can simply remove that attribute.

```js
// jQuery
$('[name="LOCATION"]').attr('onchange', false)

// Plain JS version 
// document.querySelector('[name="LOCATION"]').removeAttribute('onchange')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="LOCATION" size="1" onchange="console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
  <option>Jump To...</option>
  <option value="test1">Feb 2021</option>
  <option value="test2">Mar 2021</option>
</select>
```